# How to run a simple botium test against watson

Tags: testing, chatbot

I am attempting to test [botium](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/wiki/The-Botium-CLI) against watson assistant following the wiki.

Running:

- MacOS High Sierra 10.13.06
- Node 8.10
- Npm 6.4.1

Step by step what I did:

- I installed botium-cli: `npm i botium-cli -g`
- Setup the following folder structure

[image]

Where this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "botium",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "emulator": "botium-cli emulator console --convos ./spec/convos --config ./botium.json",
    "emulatorBrowser": "botium-cli emulator browser --convos ./spec/convos --config ./botium.json"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And this is my botium.json:

```
{
    "botium": {
      "Capabilities": {
        "PROJECTNAME": "botium-sample1",
        "CONTAINERMODE": "watsonconversation",
        "WATSON_URL": "https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api",
        "WATSON_USER": "<WATSON_USER_ID>",
        "WATSON_PASSWORD": "<WATSON_PASSWORD",
        "WATSON_WORKSPACE_ID": "<WATSON_WORKSPACE_ID>"
      },
      "Sources": {},
      "Envs": {
        "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED": 0
      }
    }
}
```

**Expected behavior:**

As I execute `npm run emulator` I would expect botium to send the utterances specified in `spec/convos/captain.convo.txt` to watson and compare this against the specified test.

**Actual behavior:**

```
Error: Loading Botium plugin failed
    at Validate.Validate.then (/Users/user/workspace/testing/botium/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/botium-core/src/containers/PluginConnectorContainer.js:56:15)
    at <anonymous>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CONTAINERMODE capability should be set to "watson":

```
{
    "botium": {
      "Capabilities": {
        ...
        "CONTAINERMODE": "watson",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

For previous versions of Botium, the containermode "watsonconversation" was fine, but this has been changed. There are still some samples around using the old container mode, they won't work anymore.

For more information on the supported capabilities, please consult the [Botium Wiki](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/wiki/operation-mode-watson).